# How to undo unshelved changes in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Can not find straightforward way to undo unshelved changes. Currently using next steps, but hope that i missed something in TFS functionality:

1. Suspend current work
2. Unshelve shelveset
3. Undo shelveset changes
4. Restore suspended items

Could not find better way. This is common scenario for code reviews or when you want to check someones changes.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing someting, but why don't you shelve your changes first (without keeping them in your workspace so that your workspace is clean), then unshelve the shelveset you want to check, undo the changes and unshelve your shelveset again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of unshelving the shelveset you want to check into a workspace that also has changes, I'd propose to get a clean workspace first,

1. either by shelving your current changes (without keeping the changes in the workspace)
2. or by doing a check-in.

This way, you start the code review with a clean workspace and you can easily undo the changes of the shelveset when you are finished.

Comment: Suspend - create shelve with current changes and undo them. But i hoped that exists some way to undo unschelve operation in one click

Comment: I don't know of a specific "un-unshelve" command. The easiest way I know is to undo the changes in the Pending Changes window at the root so that all changes are undone at once.

Comment: What do you think, may be it worth to have different workspace for such tasks?

Comment: Hmm, even in a separate workspace, you'd have to get the latest version and also undo the changes before getting the new shelveset for a review. Maybe it's best to wait with the reviews until you do a check-in anyway; this way the undo is not easier, but you don't have to create a shelveset for your changes and unshelve them later on. So you'd save steps 1 and 4 in your process.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible in my current project. Priority of code review is higher then development and all developers have to make code review. Anyway thank you for help.